# How to get email from facebook through Guzzle in laravel?

Tags: facebook, laravel, guzzle

I am using below code to login via facebook in laravel.

Referring https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps for token based authentication and using https://github.com/sahat/satellizer for social media integration.

```
$params = [
        'code' => $request->input('code'),
        'client_id' => $request->input('clientId'),
        'redirect_uri' => $request->input('redirectUri'),
        'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        /*'client_secret' => Config::get('app.facebook_secret')*/
    ];

    // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
    $accessTokenResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token', [
        'query' => $params
    ]);
    $accessToken = json_decode($accessTokenResponse->getBody(), true);

    // Step 2. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
    $profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
        'query' => $accessToken
    ]);
    $profile = json_decode($profileResponse->getBody(), true);
```

$profile returning only fb id and user name.
What changes should I do to get email from facebook.

Comment: I know your question is specifically asking about Guzzle, however the [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) package might be worth checking out - it offers social authentication for a lot of providers (Twitter, Facebook, Google, Github, etc) and there are third party providers that you can easily add.  You also might want to check out [Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com) as a replacement to Guzzle - it has better documentation.

Comment: I would have to disagree with this comment.  Guzzle, and its documentation appears to be good enough for the likes of Google https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client, Facebook https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 and Goutte https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your step 2.

```
$fields = 'id,email,first_name,last_name,link,name';
$profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
'query' => [
    'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
    'fields' => $fields
]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me'
```

with this:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=name,email'
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields", see changelog.

Also, you need to authorize with the `email` permission, of course. And the email has to be confirmed. You can´t be 100% sure to get an email, some users use their phone number to login.

You should also check this out: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/615

Comment: it may be a bit different with laravel/guzzle, but you must define the fields you want to get back with the "fields" parameter.

Comment: enable debugging within the GuzzleHttp\Client by using the 'debug' => true request option.  What is the output? What is the exact uri that your request is sending to Facebook?  Furthermore, why not simply use Facebook's SDK?  You would be advised to also refer to the document that @luschn linked to above.  I would also advise you read the Facebook Developers Documentation available at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted  Scroll down and look at the Uri's that are being used.

Comment: i am not sure why people use php for this anyway, the javascript sdk is so much easier to handle. just saying ;)

Comment: I have access to read users email in facebook developer's account . Still I can't get email from facebook. Tried with many possibility. only getting display name and id.